# JQuery Validate Plugin Error Class

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, validation, jquery-validate

I want to edit the error message outside of the validate function. So I have a simple password recovery form. Here's the html:

```
<div style="position:relative; left:40%;" class="pass_recovery">
    <h2 class="title">Recover</h2>
    <form action="" method="POST" id="recover_pass">
        <span style="font-size:12px;">Email you registered with: </span><input type="text" name="recov_pass" id="recov_pass"<br>
        <input type="submit" value="Send Password">
    </form><br>
</div>
```

And here's my jquery for the validation:

```
var pass_rec = $('#recover_pass').validate({
    onkeyup: false,
    errorClass: "password_messages",
    rules: {
        recov_pass: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        recov_pass: {
            required: "Please enter an email address",
            email: "Please enter a valid email address"
        }
    }
});
```

And then the ajax call. This simply checks if the inputted email is a valid, registered email address.

```
$('#recover_pass').submit(function() {
    if(pass_rec.form()) {
        var $this = $(this);  
        $.ajax({
            data: $this.serialize(), // get the form data
            type: "POST", // GET or POST
            url: "Private/Recover_pass.php", // the file to call
            success: function(data) { // on success..
                if(data=="pass") { 
                    $('.password_messages').text('good');
                }
                else {
                    $('.password_messages').text('bad');
                }
            },
            error: function(data) {
                $('.password_messages').text('error');
            },
            complete: function(data) {
                $('#recov_pass').val("");
            }
        });
    }
    return false; //so it doesn't refresh when submitting the page
});
```

This doesn't work because when I entered in a dummy email that isn't registered, say `example@ex.com`, then it doesn't display the `bad` message. How do I show the error message outside of the validation function?

Comment: What does Private/Recover_pass.php return?  maybe add `console.log(data)` inside your success function

Comment: @JasonSperske I know for a fact it returns the string properly. Because before this I just a `<p>` that I would do `.text(data)` on and it would display just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to put the result string into an area on your page that has a class of '.password_messages' but I do not see that in your html example code. Are you sure it is somewhere on your page?

You should have a target like:

```
<span class='.password_messages'></span>
```

and that is where you would expect to see the result text, right?